# Case-insensitive enum in ASP .NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, enums, asp.net-4.5

In my web API, I have an endpoint for CRUD operations on an object that contains `enum` Properties.

```
// User.cs
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Platform Platform { get; set; }
}

public enum Platform
{
    Windows, Linux, MacOS
}

// UserController.cs
public class UserController : ApiController 
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(User value)
    {
        users.Add(value);
        return Ok();
    }
    //...
}
```

When the endpoint is called with the following payload, it works fine:

```
{"Username": "jason", "Platform": "Linux"}
```

ASP .NET parses the enum value correctly as `Platform.Linux`
However, if the casing is different, e.g:

```
{"Username": "jason", "Platform": "linux"}
```

Then ASP .NET will not recognize this as `Platform.Linux` and will instead silently use the default value `Platform.Windows`.

The API gets requests from other services that I cannot change, so I have to support both variants of casing.

I know that I can just use two equivalent enum values with different casing like this:

```
public enum Platform
{
    Windows=0, windows=0,
    Linux=1, linux=1,
    MacOS=2, macos=2
}
```

But I wonder if there's a better solution?

Comment: I'm on .NET Framework 4.5.2; The Version of the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi Package is 5.2.3

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in my case, there was a custom converter being used for the object before it was passed to the controller. That converter used `Enum.TryParse` to parse the value:

```
if (Enum.TryParse(enumLiteral, out result))
{
    return result;
}
```

I changed this to

```
if (Enum.TryParse(enumLiteral, true, out result))
{
    return result;
}
```

Which made the parsing case-insensitive.

Note that this was a custom converter that is not part of ASP.NET itself. The issue did not occur when I removed that converter entirely and only using native functionality.